Can Mark 16:1 or Luke 23:56, be understood in the original Greek to mean something other than the popular English translations?
Mark 16:1:

(NKJV) Now when the Sabbath was past, Mary Magdalene, Mary the mother of James, and Salome bought spices, that they might come and anoint Him.
(NLT) … when the Sabbath ended, Mary Magdalene, Mary the mother of James, and Salome went out and purchased burial spices so they could anoint Jesus’ body.

Luke 23:56:

(NKJV) Then they returned and prepared spices and fragrant oils. And they rested on the Sabbath according to the commandment.
(NLT) Then they went home and prepared spices and ointments to anoint his body. But by the time they were finished the Sabbath had begun, so they rested as required by the law.

As translated into English, these two verses say:

There was a sabbath day.
Then the women bought and prepared spices on a non-sabbath day.
Then there was a sabbath day.

Can the original Greek for these verses be interpreted without leading to the same logical conclusion as the usual English translations?
Note:

This question is not asking about contradiction, nor about inclusive counting, nor whether the 15th can properly be called a sabbath, nor considering the overall context of the narrative.
This question is strictly about the possible meanings of the Greek words and grammar in these two verses.
This is not a duplicate of What is the context in Mark and Luke as regards the buying and preparing of the spices?,
as it asks about the context of the events, which are irrelevant to this question.


Introduction
Mark 16:1 and Luke 23:56 are complementary details of the same series of events. These narrations complete the whole picture in more clarity.
Explanation
Since the OP is not looking for clarification of a contradiction, inclusive counting, 15th Sabbath or the relevant context but only for the possible meaning of the Greek words and grammar, we will also limit our study to the latter.
The literal translation of the Greek is as follows:
Mark 16:1:

“And having passed (perfect participle) the Sabbath, Mary the
Magdalene and Mary the of the James and Salome bought (simple
past) spices, that having come (perfect participle) they
might anoint Him.” (Biblehub)

In the above verse:

“having passed” is “aorist participle middle verb” which in English is “perfect participle” in the non-finite (not real) verb. This could be termed as an “adverbial phrase”.

A google search gives the following description: In the New Testament, an aorist participle middle verb in Greek can be used to describe an action that happened before the main verb……When the Greek middle voice verb form is used, the subject of the verb is seen as acting upon itself or for its own benefit.”
So, “the Sabbath having passed itself”!

“bought” is “aorist indicative active verb” which in English is “simple past”.

The google search gave me this description: “The aorist indicative active verb in the Greek New Testament is a verb that describes a past action in a simple past tense……The aorist describes a single, complete action, rather than an ongoing, repeated, or habitual action.” (emphasis mine).
So, after a Sabbath they bought the spices.

“having come” is “aorist participle active” which in English is “perfect participle”.

The google search gives the description: “In the Greek New Testament, an aorist participle is a verb that describes an action that typically takes place before the main verb of a sentence.”
So, after coming to the Tomb, they could anoint Him.
Conclusion 1

Sabbath is over;

Mary Magdalene, Mary of James and Salome bought spices; and

Their purpose is “that” they may come and anoint Him.


Spices happened AFTER Sabbath.
Luke 23:56:

“Having returned (perfect participle) then they prepared
(simple past) spices and anointing oils. And on the indeed Sabbath
they rested (simple past) according to the commandment” (Biblehub).

In the above verse:

“having returned” is “aorist participle active” which in English is “perfect participle” in the non-finite (not real) verb. This could be termed as an “adverbial phrase”.

The google search gives the description: “In the Greek New Testament, an aorist participle is a verb that describes an action that typically takes place before the main verb of a sentence.”
So, they were not at home but were at the Tomb witnessing the Crucifixion and burial. But afterwards they returned home. Then what?

“they prepared” and “they rested” are in “aorist indicative active verb” forms which in English mean “simple past”.

The google search gave me this description: “The aorist indicative active verb in the Greek New Testament is a verb that describes a past action in a simple past tense……The aorist describes a single, complete action, rather than an ongoing, repeated, or habitual action.”
Conclusion 2

They returned from the Tomb;

They “prepared” the spices and oils (which they had bought earlier) by grinding and drying; and

They rested on the Sabbath according to the commandment.


Spices happened BEFORE the Sabbath

That is not what the texts are saying.  This question hinges on the subtleties of the Greek tenses.
Mark 15:46, 47, 16:1

So Joseph bought a linen cloth, took down the body of Jesus, wrapped
it in the cloth, and placed it in a tomb that had been cut out of the
rock. Then he rolled a stone against the entrance to the tomb. Mary
Magdalene and Mary the mother of Joseph saw where His body was placed.
When the Sabbath was over, Mary Magdalene, Mary the mother of James,
and Salome bought spices so they could go and anoint the body of
Jesus.

The verb for "bought" is ἠγόρασαν which is aorist indicative active, suggesting that this was a past act.  If this was very early in the morning, then the women presumably had bought their spices late on Friday afternoon because traders would not normally be open before sunrise on Sunday morning.
Luke 23:55, 56, 24:1

The women who had come with Jesus from Galilee followed, and they saw
the tomb and how His body was placed. Then they returned to prepare
spices and perfumes. And they rested on the Sabbath, according to the
commandment.
On the first day of the week, very early in the morning, the women
came to the tomb, bringing the spices they had prepared.

This simply confirms the parallel account in Mark that the spices had been purchased and prepared before coming to the tomb, presumably soon after Jesus died, before the Sabbath and then brought to the tomb to anoint/embalm the body.
Indeed, the record in John 19:38-40 suggests that the spices were purchased/supplied by Joseph of Arimathea and Nicodemus amounting to about "a hundred litras".

Are you saying that Mark 16:1 should be "Mary … so they could go and anoint the body of Jesus when the sabbath was over."? If so, why do no translations have it that way? They all seem to pair the "when" clause with "bought", not with "anoint".

@RayButterworth - no - the English is quite straight forward, "When the Sabbath was over, Mary Magdalene, Mary the mother of James, and Salome bought spices so they could go and anoint the body of Jesus. Very early on the first day of the week, just after sunrise, they went to the tomb."

So I'm even more confused now. Your answer says "the women presumably had bought their spices late on Friday afternoon" but your comment now says "When the Sabbath was over [they] bought spices". Are you saying that the Greek could mean it either way?

@RayButterworth - the verb "bought" is in a past time and is a past event - anytime earlier would be consistent with the tense of the verb.  That is, they buy the spices on Friday afternoon and on Sunday morning Mark reports that they had bought spices which they took to the tomb.

In Mark 16:1, I still don't see what "When the sabbath was over" refers to if not "bought" or "anoint".

@RayButterworth - "bought spices" is probably is an adverbial phrase of explanation modifying the verb "having come to anoint".  That is, the sentence is saying, "after the Sabbath, having bought spices they were coming to anoint the body of Jesus."
